# Missing responseText Information (vb6 call)

Tags: json, vb6, responsetext, serverxmlhttp

This problem has been driving me crazy, hopefully someone out there knows the answer as I couldn't find one searching around.

I am trying to access a web service in one of our legacy vb6 apps with the following:

```
Dim xmlHttpRequest As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
Dim xmlParameters As String
Dim timeOutValue As Long

timeOutValue = 300 * 1000&
xmlParameters = "TradingPartnerName=" + inTradingPartnerName
Set xmlHttpRequest = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
xmlHttpRequest.Open "POST", urlString, False
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader "Host", "xa-2k8:2016/"
xmlHttpRequest.setTimeouts timeOutValue, timeOutValue, timeOutValue, timeOutValue

xmlHttpRequest.sEnd (xmlParameters)
```

It essentially makes the api call with the parameter "TradingPartnerName" with a value (in this case "DSSI").  It will then return a JSON result which gets parsed out later on.

What I get back from looking at wireshark is the following:

[image: WireShark results]

All of the right data is there...

When I look at xmlHttpRequest.responseText after the send (or decode .responseBody) I get the following:

```
ResponseText : "{"$id":"1","TradingPartnerInformation":{"$id":"2","$values":[{"$id":"3","TradingPartnerKey":1,"TpName":"DSSI","SenderIdQualifier":"12","SenderId":"(removed)","ReceiverIdQualif"
```

It truncates at 429 char's every time

Here is the content type being sent back:
Content-Type → application/json; charset=utf-8

Am I doing something wrong?  Or is it a bug in the library?  I also tried with WinHTTP 5.1 and got the exact result.

From all the other examples I saw on stackoverflow, people were missing data in their wireshark analysis as well.  In my case, I see all the right data being returned, so I just don't get why it is getting truncated.

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

EDIT:
I played with the encoding digging deeper into GSerg's suggestion...  and found using different decode types has different results when I convert responseBody from binary to a string.

With the following method:

```
Function BinaryToString(ByVal Binary)
    BinaryToString = ""
    Dim BinaryStream
    Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

    BinaryStream.Type = 1 '--- adTypeBinary

    BinaryStream.Open
    BinaryStream.Write Binary

    BinaryStream.Position = 0
    BinaryStream.Type = 2 '--- adTypeText

    BinaryStream.Charset = (UTF-8 or ASCII)

    BinaryToString = BinaryStream.ReadText
End Function
```

If I make the charset "UTF-8" I get the following:

```
"{"$id":"1","TradingPartnerInformation":{"$id":"2","$values":[{"$id":"3","TradingPartnerKey":1,"TpName":"DSSI","SenderIdQualifier":"12","SenderId":"(removed)","ReceiverIdQua
```

If I make the charset "ASCII" I get the following:

```
"{"$id":"1","TradingPartnerInformation":{"$id":"2","$values":[{"$id":"3","TradingPartnerKey":1,"TpName":"DSSI","SenderIdQualifier":"12","SenderId":"(removed)","ReceiverIdQualifier":"12","ReceiverId":"(removed)","ElementSeparator":"*","SubElementSea"
```

So, it seems it is an encoding problem, but still not getting the full result set when switching to ASCII

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/q/10451064/11683 help?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!  But sadly no, I came across that one earlier and when I tried using responseBody instead, it was truncated to the exact same spot once converted to a string.

Comment: GSerg, your answer actually was the right one.  It took me a little bit to figure this out, but with all the edit info I added - "responseBody" did start sending all data, but the debugger would still only show a portion of the response if I put a watch on test = BinaryToString(xmlHttpRequest.responseBody).  If I sent it to a message box though, the complete value would display.  So it looks like I was hitting a limitation for that field in the debugger only.

Thanks for the help!  Add it as an answer and I will accept it.  Thanks again!

Comment: I did not actually answer, so I don't really have anything to post. If you have found a useful clarification to the asnwer I linked to, you should post that and accept, otherwise it's a close as duplicate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a limitation of the vb6 debugger itself.  It was not displaying the full response even though it was in fact there if I outputted to a message box or file.

[Using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP to access data from a web page returns truncated data in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10451064/11683) helped draw this conclusion